# is it possible to create multiple spring beans (from different interfaces) with the same name?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create the following structure:

```
public interface A {string calculateA(){....}}

@Service("policy1")
public class APolicy1 implements A {
  @Override
  public String calculateA(){...}
}

@Service("policy2")
public class APolicy2 implements A {
  @Override
  public String calculateA(){...}
}
```

and another interface

```
 public interface B{string calculateB(){....}}

@Service("policy1")
public class BPolicy1 implements B{
  @Override
  public String calculateB(){...}
}

@Service("policy2")
public class BPolicy2 implements B{
  @Override
  public String calculateB(){...}
}
```

and the classes that uses these beans:

```
@service
@Primary
public class Arouter implements A{
   @Autowired
   Map<String, A> AServices;

   @Autowired
   PolicyResolver policyResolver;

   @Override
   public String calculateA(){
     String policy = policyResolver.getPolicy();
     AServices.get(policy).CalculateA();
}

@service
@Primary
public class Brouter Implements B{
   @Autowired
   Map<String, B> AServices;

   @Autowired
   PolicyResolver policyResolver;

   @Override
   public String calculateB(){
     String policy = policyResolver.getPolicy();
     AServices.get(policy).CalculateB();
}
```

note: the idea here is to delegate to the correct business logic by some kind of policy
for example, if i'm running in policy a context and need to trigger Service B, then the router will call BPolicy2 method.

but I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'policy1' for bean class [...apackage.APolicy1] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [...bpackage.BPolicy1]
```

I would expect that since these are different bean types I would be able to give them the same name

edit: I have a solution: add a prefix to the beans the name and the routers will add the prefix to the policyResolver return value, but I'm it's less elegant

Comment: Why do they need to have the same name? Where do you depend on the name?

Comment: thanks for replying, the router calculates a policy (will be either "policy1" or "policy2")
and then get a bean from the autowired map by the calculated policy and use the same method, I'll update the question with this info, but still not sure how it is relevant to the question.

Comment: Two beans can't have the same name, it may be better to make a custom annotation which defines policy, then use that to identify which bean to use.

Comment: @123 how can I use the annotation to determine which bean to use? if you mean by using AOP I would rather not since it will breaks the OCP, I probably would need to add another policy and and another bean for that policy, and I don't want to touch existing code

Comment: You'd just do what spring does with beans but manually. So add `@Policy("1")` ,or whatever you annotation will be called, to the class and then map all the beans with that annotation when the app starts up. Then you can just query the map for whatever you want.

Comment: @123 I understand now, this is actually a very elegant solution, thanks for the suggestion

but I still find it strange that spring doesn't know how to handle this situation, they are beans of different interface

Answer (score -1):

@qualifier annotation can be used to differentiate between different beans.

Here is a link with small example of @qualifier annotation usage in Spring :

https://memorynotfound.com/handling-multiple-autowire-dependencies-with-spring-qualifier/

Comment: this does not in any mean relates to my use case.